# Mutable, but lockable, data-structure in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, concurrency

Is there a standard data-structure in Haskell that is mutable like an `IORef`, but, if required, can also be "locked", like an `MVar`? Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

- There are multiple threads calling on OAuth based API, and all of them need the `AccessToken`
- However, the `AccessToken` can expire, and one of these threads will be the first to know (as it will get a `401` response). Let's call this thread `T1`
- `T1` will immediately invoke the `refreshToken` function before retrying the original API call. At this point, the code need to make sure of two things:

  1. All new threads are blocked when trying to read the `AccessToken` -- till  it is refreshed, and a new `AccessToken` is made available in this shared data-structure
  2. All other threads, that may have received a `401` shortly after `T1`, are blocked on their call to `refreshToken` function.

I've already used an `IORef` to store the `AccessToken` in a mutable manner. However, I am not sure if I should use a **separate `MVar`** to protect concurrent access to the `refreshToken` function. Is there an in-built data-structure that does this already?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not familiar with that specific API, but it sounds to me like you may want to just store the token, and a counter indicating how many times it's been refreshed, in an `MVar`. One thread is responsible for initially filling the `MVar` with the token. Each thread that needs the token calls `readMVar` to get it.

When a thread discovers that the token has expired, it calls `tryTakeMVar` to take control of the token. If that fails, then some other thread has taken control, and this one goes back to `readMVar`. If it succeeds, it checks that the counter is what it expected. If it's not, some other thread already refreshed the token and it just puts it back. If it is, then it refreshes the token, increments the counter, and puts those in the `MVar` before continuing on its way. You'll want to be careful about exception safety as usual for locking protocols; there are some `MVar` functions available to help with that.

As I've described it, the scheme requires that one thread be responsible for initialization. If you want to acquire the token only when you first need it, you'll have to make one small adjustment: store a `Maybe` in the `MVar`, initialized to `Nothing`.

The following code assumes functions `acquireToken` and `refreshToken` to acquire a token initially and refresh an existing one, respectively. Obviously you can adjust accordingly if those operations are actually done the same way. The `restore` below is used in case refreshing the token involves a substantial amount of computation; we don't want to make the thread unkillable while it's doing that.

```
newtype TokBox = TB (MVar (Maybe (Word, AccessToken)))

newTokBox :: IO TokBox
newTokBox = TB <$> newMVar Nothing

-- | Get a (possibly expired) token and an action to use if that
-- token is expired. The result
-- should only be used once.
getToken :: TokBox -> IO (AccessToken, IO ())
getToken tb@(TB mv) = do
  contents <- readMVar mv
  case contents of
    Nothing -> refresh Nothing tb
    Just (_, t) -> pure (t, refresh contents tb)

-- Refresh the access token, expecting the MVar to have particular contents.
refresh :: Maybe (Word, AccessToken) -> TokBox -> IO ()
refresh old (TB mv) =
  mask $ \restore ->
    tryTakeMVar mv >>= \case
      -- Another thread is refreshing
      Nothing -> pure ()
      Just cont
        -- Another thread refreshed; we restore the MVar
        | not $ sameContents cont old
        = putMVar mv cont
        | otherwise
        = (restore $ case cont of
             Nothing -> do
               tok <- acquireToken
               putMVar mv (Just (0, tok))
             Just (count, tok) -> do
               tok' <- refreshToken tok
               putMVar mv (Just (count + 1, tok')))
                `onException`
                  putMVar cont

sameContents :: Maybe (Word, a) -> Maybe (Word, b) -> Bool
sameContents Nothing Nothing = True
sameContents (Just (m, _)) (Just (n, _)) = m == n
sameContents _ _ = False
```